# MVC Use _Layout in different views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, layout

I have set up a layout with a sidebar which I'd like to be in all of the views in my application. In the main view everything is OK, but when I try to apply it to 'Contact' view, nothing happens, the view is empty.

I'm doing:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

at the beggining of Contacts.html.

Any idea?

Comment: why not put layout in viewstart

Comment: can u provide more detail. Exact issue you are facing,

Comment: Your code looks correct. with out more detail there's not much else to say.  As a pointer i would check to see if the action i am calling to open "contacts" is actually opening the view i require (check your folders are correct).